# Unable to resolve an interface with Unity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, mocking, unity-container

***Question background:***

I am using unity to resolve a class and all its dependencies.

***The issue:***

I want to pass into the constructor of the classes an interface type through Unity, I'm attempting to achieve this as follows:

```
public static IFacade UnityNewsFacadeResolver()
   {
           IUnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
           unityContainer.RegisterType<IFacade, NewsFacade>();
           IFacade newsFacadeInstance = unityContainer.Resolve<NewsFacade>();

           return newsFacadeInstance;
   }
```

The following shows the 'NewsFacade' class that Unity sets the constructor parameter. Note it is passing in a 'NewsStoryHandler' concrete type, I want to pass in the interface this class is based on i.e INewsStoryHandler:

```
private INewsStoryHandler _NewsStoryHandler;

    //*****Unity will only pass in a concrete implementation, I want to pass it as an interface but cannot:******
    public NewsFacade(NewsStoryHandler newsStoryHandler)
    {
        if (newsStoryHandler == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("newsStoryHandler is null at the constrcutor");
        }

        _NewsStoryHandler = newsStoryHandler;
    }
```

Currently Unity will not resolve and pass in an Interface type, it has to be a concrete implementation as shown above. This means I cannot Mock the interface when I unit test.

Can someone tell me why Unity will not resolve and pass in a type based on its interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity is perfectly capable of resolving and providing a type based upon its interface.

To do so you must ensure that unity knows what concrete implementation to provide, i.e.

```
// Instruct unity to inject a NewsStoryHandler everywhere an INewsStoryHandler is specified
unityContainer.RegisterType<INewsStoryHandler, NewsStoryHandler>();
var newsFacadeInstance = unityContainer.Resolve<NewsFacade>();
```

This works assuming you have changed your `NewsFacade` constructor to have a parameter of type `INewsStoryHandler`.

When it comes to unit testing, you are then able to mock the `INewsStoryHandler` to make testing of your `NewsFacade` simpler, an example using Moq:

```
// Setup and configure the mock
var mockNewsStoryHandler = new Mock<INewsStoryHandler>();
mockNewsStoryHandler.Setup(h => h.GetAllStories()).Returns(Enumerable.Empty<NewsStory>());

// Inject the mock
var newsFacade = new NewsFacade(mockNewsStoryHandler.Object);
newsFacade.DoSomethingWithAllStories();

// Verify GetAllStories() was called exactly once
mockNewsStoryHandler.Verify(h => h.GetAllStories(), Times.Once);
```

Comment: Excellent answer. That got it all working. If I can ask another question. I have three class, the 'top level' class if the Facade, this consumes the 'NewsHandler' and this consumes a 'NewsRepository' each set at the consumers constructor. How would I go setting up and returning the bottom level object? I.e the news repository?

Comment: You can configure unity to inject the correct repository, i.e. `unityContainer.RegisterType<INewsRepository, NewsRepository>()` then when resolving the facade, the repository will be injected into the news handler, which will be injected into the facade.